# How to install libusb-1.0 on Windows Mingw

Tags: windows, mingw-w64, pkg-config, libusb-1.0

I have downloaded the binaries for libusb-1.0 and now need to add the library to my Mingw installation. I have tried adding the library to the "C:\Program Files (x86)\mingw-w64\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\mingw32\lib" but the library is not found using "pkg-config --exists libusb-1.0"

Could use some help please.